# @XmlElement and useless 'required' parameter

Tags: java, jaxb

I put  **@XmlElement(name = "title",required = true)** before the javabean property
**int some_property**, and didn't assign a value to **some_property**. For some reason this property is not occurred in generated XML. So, please, explain the meaning of **required**

some meaningful parts of the code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "author", "name", "publisher", "isbn" })
public class Book {

private String name;
private String author;
private String publisher;
private String isbn;

// If you like the variable name, e.g. "name", you can easily change this
// name for your XML-Output:
@XmlElement(name = "title",required = true)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
....
```

Somewhere int the **Main** :

```
    // create books
    Book book1 = new Book();
    book1.setIsbn("978-0060554736");

    book1.setAuthor("Neil Strauss");
    book1.setPublisher("Harpercollins");
    bookList.add(book1);


    Book book2 = new Book();
    book2.setIsbn("978-3832180577");
    book2.setName("Feuchtgebiete");
    book2.setAuthor("Charlotte Roche");
    book2.setPublisher("Dumont Buchverlag");
    bookList.add(book2);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bookstore.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    // Write to System.out
    m.marshal(bookstore, System.out);

    // Write to File
    m.marshal(bookstore, new File(BOOKSTORE_XML));

    // get variables from our xml file, created before
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Output from our XML File: ");
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Bookstore bookstore2 = (Bookstore) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(BOOKSTORE_XML));
    ArrayList<Book> list = bookstore2.getBooksList();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### What `required` Does on `@XmlElement`

The `required` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation affects the XML schema that is generated from Java classes.

**Domain Model (Root)**

Below is a simple Java model.  Note how the `bar` property has `required=true` and the `foo` property does not.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement
    private String foo;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String bar;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    private String baz;

}
```

**Demo Code**

Below is some code that demonstrates how to generate an XML schema using the `JAXBContext`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class GenerateSchema {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {
            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri,
                    String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Generated XML Schema**

Below is the resulting XML schema note how the XML element corresponding to the `foo` field has `minOccurs="0"` while the XML element corresponding to the `bar` field (which was annotated with `@XmlElement(required=true)` does not.  This is because the default `minOccurs` is 1 meaning it's required.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root" type="root"/>
  <xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="baz" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### If You Want an Element for `null` Values

**Domain Model (Root)**

The `baz` field has been annotated with `@XmlElement(nillable=true)`. If the value is null the resulting XML element will leverage the `xsi:nil` attribute.  Without this annotation null values will be treated as absent nodes.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement
    private String foo;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String bar;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    private String baz;

}
```

**Demo Code**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class MarshalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the resulting XML from running the demo code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <baz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</root>
```

Comment: But it said that **@XmlElement(required=true)** guarantee value to be printed in XML , as we can see there are no **bar** value in the result XML

Comment: @voipp - Where does it say that?

Comment: unfortunately i can not find. So thanx for the answer.

Comment: Beautifully explained! Short and Sweet! Crystal clear!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: So required=true is mean: minOccurs=1  but it's not mean its OCCUR in the result request?

Answer (score 1):

From: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html

> **public abstract boolean required**
>
> Customize the element declaration to be required.
>   If required() is true, then Javabean property is mapped to an XML schema element declaration with minOccurs="1". maxOccurs is "1" for a single valued property and "unbounded" for a multivalued property.
>
> If required() is false, then the Javabean property is mapped to XML Schema element declaration with minOccurs="0". maxOccurs is "1" for a single valued property and "unbounded" for a multivalued property.

Your property is mapped to an element that is (hopefully) declared as required in the schema. Your generated XML is not compliant to that particular schema, which is more or less what I expected from an instance that does not "play by the rules" it has laid out

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us a sample of your code and generated xml?
According to docs:

> If required is true, then Javabean property is mapped to an XML schema
>   element declaration with minOccurs="1". maxOccurs is "1" for a single
>   valued property and "unbounded" for a multivalued property.